# Hyper-V installed and enabled

Tags: hyper-v

I can see that Hyper-V installed with the following command Get-WindowsFeature and get back a long list where I can see that Hyper-V is crossed under Display name and Installed under Install State.

But with the following powershell snippet,I can see that Hyper-V is disabled.

```
$hyperv = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online
# Check if Hyper-V is enabled
if($hyperv.State -eq "Enabled") {
    Write-Host "Hyper-V is enabled."
} else {
   Write-Host "Hyper-V is disabled."
```

I think it has to be enabled , how to enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as Get-WindowsFeature shows that Hyper-V is installed, it is enabled. There is no need to enable it.